# How to validate Cluster(anylsis) for high dimensional Data (gene expression)

Tags: validation, bigdata, cluster-analysis

Hello I'm new here I hope I have entered everything correctly and this question is in the right forum. Also, I have checked before and no previous question seems to be comparable with this one.

To my question:
I am currently working on the validation of cluster methods using the package clValid. Now my dataset with which I work is very large (1,000 to 25,000) it is gene expressions. Now the question is which methods for the validation of high dimensional data sets come into question at all. Maybe there is another package for validating clustering in high-dimesnion space. Do I have to do a PCA before? how big can my dataset be so that I can use clValdi on it (I don't want to let my computer run for hours or should I just let it run and wait for a result with a small dataset 100x500) I am grateful for every suggestion maybe there are solutions I haven't thought about yet.

clValid

Answer (score 0):

I would rather *not* rely on any of these indexes.

1. These measures usually require clusters to be complete and disjoint, and that does not hold for typical Gene biclusters. There are Genes not involved in any of the effects observed in the experiment
2. The measures we're usually designed with *low-dimensional Gaussian data* in mind, and once you have such high dimensional data where all distances are large, they measure that there is no contrast between clusters (because their measure does not see contrast between any two data points

I fear that you may need to evaluate by complex, domain-specitic analysis.